# Why the sign of RHO in BSM and Black76 Model is opposite?

Tags: black-scholes, greeks, black76

I find the formula of RHO using Black76 model ([Source](https://www.glynholton.com/notes/black_1976/), alternatively see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)) and scroll to "Under the Black model"):
$$ RHO_{call} = -t*c $$
$$RHO_{put} = -t*p$$
which means the sign of rho < 0.

But when use BSM ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks))， the $RHO_{call}>0,RHO_{put}<0$, so I am very confused.
I'll very appreciate for anyone's help!

Comment: I suspect your first source may have a typo. I'd go with the Wiki formulas.

Comment: Black76 in your Wiki source is the Black model (scroll down). This is also negative, correct and identical.

Comment: The wiki, lower down after "Under the Black model", also shows both Black76 rho's to be negative.

Comment: @nbbo2, you beat me!

Comment: If your actual question is why BSM has a different rho from Black76, in Black, you look at forwards / futures and the interest shows up nowhere in the formula (F is given from the market, d1 and d2 do not contain it). So if rates increase, all that changes is your discount rate, hence its negative (more discounting).

Comment: ... while in BSM, you have the right to buy / sell spot at some future date. The right to buy  means you do not forgo interest (as you still have that money at your disposal). If you have the right to sell (Long put), you could have sold it already, meaning you forgo the potential interest income. With fwds / futures you also get the right to buy and sell, but the fwd / future price already incorporates the cost of carry (what you could have earned)

Comment: Yes, @nbbo2 and AKdemy are correct (I was looking at the wrong table)

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I also have a question, if rho of Black76 = rho  of BSM, then $-te^{-rt}F\phi(d_1)=0$, but why it equal to 0?@AKdemy,

Comment: Not sure I follow the reason for the last question. Seems you simply set them equal by assumption and see what the terms are? However, for the same underlying, the ATM strike for the future (ATMS) will not equal the one for spot (ATMF) either and have a separate vol surface (option chain). It's in essence a different model for a different underlying.

Comment: yes, i assumpt the rho of two model is equal to see when the black76 model is applicable to the BSM. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AKdemy, I have repeatedly read your description of why the black76 model's rho is negative, but still have not understood, could you please to give a detailed decription? If the futures price calculation formula exists($F = Se^{-rt}$), the price calculation of BSM and Black76 is the same, but the rho is different.

Comment: Hester S: options on stock (BSM) and options on futures (B76) are different in the cash flows that will occur, hence their sensitivity (Rho) to interest rates is also different.

Comment: @nbbo2 Thank you!